# How can i display images in angular app while images are stored in node.js server uploads folder?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, image, express

I have a `node.js` server(separate directory) where i am saving files in `uploads` folder and saving image path in `db`. I have following directory structure in my `node.js` server

```
node_modules
src
uploads
 |category-name-folder
    |image-name.jpg
 |category-name-folder
    |image-name.jpg
package.json
```

i am saving `image path` in `db` like this `uploads/category-name/image-name.jpg`.

Now i want to display all `images` in `angular` app. So please guide me how can i display these images to `angular` app? Should i send `image paths` to `angular` app via an `Api` ? if yes so what complete url should i send to `angular` app and what `url` should i bind in `angular` app `img` `src`?

**Note :** I have a separate directory structure of client app `(angular)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server side(Nodejs), serve the uploads folder statically. To Angular send the image path and give it as a source for images.

```
<img [src]="imagePath">
```

The image source should be something like 'YOUR_DOMAIN/uploads/filename'. This is required for your case since you are providing the angular index.html in a separate domain(server).

Use this link if you are using [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: what url will be if i am in local machine? if my node server is running on `5001` and images are uploaded in `uploads` so will my url be `http://localhost:5001/uploads/image-name.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is create a GET endpoint in your node server to return the image, something like:

`[GET]images/{folder}/{imageName}`

And instead of saving the image path, you can save the URL to call that endpoint:

```
uploadedObj {
 url : config.domain + 'images/' + folder + '/image.jpg'
 }
```

Then when you get the data in your angular, you put that value directly in the image src.

```
<img src="{{ upload.url }}" *ngFor="let upload of uploads"/>
```